# Which database should I search to find the year that homes were built?

Tags: data-request, real-estate

I am working on a research project right now and need to find out what year every house within the Denver metro area was built. I have searched through DRCOG and Census data, but have been unable to find it. It would be great to get this as a .shp file, but I'm dubious on whether or not this exists so any .csv or excel file will work as well.

Comment: In Australia, I believe this would be LandGate, which charges about $20 per request. I suspect in Denver a similar goverment deparment exists. Look for which departments need to have documents requested from when you buy/sell a house -- it will normally include this kinda info.
They may have a open data policy. But I doubt it.

Answer (score 4):

Census data isn't going to provide information on individual buildings, but will provide summary data for the buildings within small geographic areas. For example, in the 5 year American Community Survey you can get the median year houses were built or the number of houses built in each decade at the census tract level.

For data on individual buildings, the best bet would be to see if the individual municipality publishes tax parcel or building outline data, and if year built is one of the attributes. I went into the Denver open data catalog here:

http://data.denvergov.org/

And they have shapefiles and csv for buildings and for parcels (do a search for buildings or for parcels). I downloaded and looked at them both - the buildings file didn't have many attributes, but the parcel file had several including one called CCYRBLT, which according to the metadata is year structure built, based on the property assessment.